# Pass get data from anchor URL

Tags: php, plugin-contact-form-7

Using the plugin Dynamic Text for Contact Form 7:

```
[dynamictext dynamictext-788 "CF7_GET key='tier'" uneditable='on' ]
```

I am trying to pass the data to the field like this:

```
<a class="x-btn lightbox-selector" href="#types?tier=Test1" data-type="inline">Register Interest</a>
```

When the user clicks the button, lightbox loads up with the contact form inside.

However, the data `Test1` is not passed in the form because I presume `href` is not a full URL? If that's the case, how can I pass the data to the form when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: Your anchors should always be at the end, anchors aren't sent to the server, and your example anchor URL includes the query string so no query is sent. This is a basic HTTP/URL issue not a WordPress or Contact Form 7 issue. Use `?tier=Test1#types` instead

Comment: Tom I tried your suggestion, but instead I am just getting an empty window.

Comment: Your empty window is a problem you didn't know you had. Most likely a white screen of death, you should look into your PHP error log to see what the issue is

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is that WordPress and your browser are interpreting everything after the "#" as a client side hash. In other words, PHP and WordPress never see the "?tier=Test1" bit.

There are few ways to fix the issue though I'm not sure which will be most efficient in your situation:

1) Trigger your modal with a JS click event instead of relying on the href attribute.

2) Store your parameters in a different attribute such as 'data-rel' and use JS to pull the parameters after the modal loads.

Comment: option 2 sounds like a plan.. but I was hoping something more simple would do.